# react typescript set default value multiselect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, default, default-value, multiple-select

I am using this module

```
import { MultiSelect } from "react-multi-select-component"
```

and creating form by this

```
const [selected_to2, setSelected_to2] = useState([]);

<MultiSelect
options={options2}
value={selected_to}
onChange={setSelected_to}
labelledBy="Select2"
/>
```

then I creating multiselect component with default value using this

```
  selected_to2.push({
    value: item?.Code,
    label: item?.Name
  })
```

but returning value with 4 time called in the multiselect form, any proper way to set default value of multiselect then also add and remove in multiselect item?

Answer (score 0):

React state must updated by set function. Edit the value directly will not work.

So you need do

```
setSelected_to2(s => [...s, {
    value: item?.Code,
    label: item?.Name
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are updating state is a wrong way

- Wrong way

```
 selected_to2.push({
    value: item?.Code,
    label: item?.Name
  })
```

- Right way:

```
setSelected_to2([{
    value: item?.Code,
    label: item?.Name
  }
])
```

Here's a quick example that I did might help you, remember your default value must be an array of selected values since it's a multiselect component.
JSX

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { MultiSelect } from "react-multi-select-component";
import "./App.css";
const options = [
  { label: "The Godfather", value: 1 },
  { label: "Pulp Fiction", value: 2 },
];
const App = ({ editMode = true }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(editMode ? [options[1]] : []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MultiSelect
        options={options}
        value={value}
        onChange={(selectedValues) => setValue(selectedValues)}
        labelledBy="Select2"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I got default value more than one

Comment: You can have multiple values in the value object, instead of one as shown in the example.